# Increase the size of the bottom navigation bar icons & delete the white space below when there is no text

Tags: android, kotlin

Noob here. First time learning to develop Android apps. Using Kotlin. Sorry if this has been answered already but the closest answer I found was in Java. I couldn't get it to work.

Please how can I increase the size of the icons in the bottom navigation bar? Also, how can I reduce/remove the white space that appears after I take out the text for the icons. I want the bar to look like the Twitter app bottom navigation bar. Please find my screen grab below.

[A screen grab of the app showing the bottom nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f702B.png)

Comment: **FYI** layout don't have to do anything with **_java_** and **_kotlin_**. Still can you provide the link to the **java solution**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your activity

```
    var i = 0
    val navigationMenuViews = bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView
    while (i < navigationMenuViews.childCount) {
        val iconView = navigationMenuViews.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.icon) as ImageView
        val layoutParams = iconView.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 48F, resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
        layoutParams.width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 48F, resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
        iconView.layoutParams = layoutParams
        i++
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I tried this and it had an effect on only the first icon. bottomNavigationView.childCount returns 1 instead of 3. Please do you know why this is the case?

Comment: @E.Thomas Ya i see that. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used code similar to above until it blew up when I updated to a new version of Material.

After a little bit of digging around this is how I do it now. You could do it programmatically of course too.

In the Layout for your BottomNavigationBar Add

app:itemIconSize="48dp"

```
   <com.myApp.UIBottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:itemIconSize="48dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/main_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```